# How to dispatch an "invalid" event for html input fields

Tags: javascript, css, dom-events, pseudo-class

> The **invalid** event is fired when a submittable element has been checked
>   and doesn't satisfy its constraints. The validity of submittable
>   elements is checked before submitting their owner form, or after the
>   checkValidity() of the element or its owner form is called.

Is it possible to create and dispatch an event under certain circumstances so that the css pseudo-class ":invalid" is triggered and/or the checkValidity function for that element returns "false"?

I'm thinking about a code snippet like this:

```
const evt = new Event("invalid", {bubbles: true, cancelable: false, composed: true});
document.getElementById("inputField").dispatchEvent(evt);
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is actually possible, based on a hack that I wrote many, many years ago at Mozilla called CSS Selector Listeners: http://www.backalleycoder.com/2012/08/06/css-selector-listeners/. To summarize the hack, it basically hijacks CSS Animations to enable the firing of an event immediately when the target selector is matched.

I have created a little demo that shows the raw hack at work to create a synthetic `invalid` event that 1) actually bubbles, and 2) is fired automatically and immediate right when an input's value enters an invalid state: https://codepen.io/csuwldcat/pen/GwBjbW

HTML:

```
<input minlength="3" maxlength="5" />
```

CSS:

```
input:invalid {
  color: red;
  animation: invalid 0.001s;
}

@keyframes invalid {
  0%: {
    outline-color: #000;
  }
}
```

JS:

```
document.addEventListener('animationstart', function(e){
  if (e.animationName == "invalid") console.log(e);
});
```